# How to configure on asterisk trunk PJSIP<->SIP?

Tags: asterisk, sip, pjsip

I've got a problem with configure trunk on asterisk with PJSIP(IP:X.X.X.X) to SIP-server(IP:Y.Y.Y.Y).
I want to configure trunk by IP not with user:pass.

On SIP-server i have config in sip.conf file like below:

```
[asterisk-pjsip]
type=peer
context=tests
host=X.X.X.X
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=X.X.X.X
qualify=yes
disallow=all
allow=g729
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
nat=yes
canreinvite=no
insecure=port,invite
```

and on SIP-server peer with PJSIP are available:

```
asterisk-pjsip            X.X.X.X                               Yes        Yes         A  5060     OK (11 ms)
```

On PJSIP-Server i use script to convert SIP.conf to PJSIP.conf
and in SIP.conf i have:

```
[asterisk_sip]
type=peer
context=tests
host=Y.Y.Y.Y
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=Y.Y.Y.Y
qualify=yes
disallow=all
allow=g729
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
nat=no
canreinvite=no
insecure=port,invite
```

and after conversion to PJSIP.conf i've got this:

```
[asterisk_sip]
type = aor
contact = sip:Y.Y.Y.Y

[asterisk_sip]
type = identify
endpoint = asterisk_sip
match = Y.Y.Y.Y

[asterisk_sip]
type = endpoint
context = tests
disallow = all
allow = g729
allow = alaw
allow = ulaw
direct_media = no
aors = asterisk_sip

[acl]
type = acl
permit = Y.Y.Y.Y
deny = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
```

and when i past it to /etc/asterisk/pjsip.conf and reload configuration peer on SIP-server are Unavailable:

```
 Endpoint:  asterisk_sip                                         Unavailable   0 of inf
  Transport:  transport-udp             udp      0      0  0.0.0.0:5060
```

Please help :)

Comment: What is question?  Some of your configs have nat=no and some nat=yes.

Comment: @arheops
i've changed to nat = yes on both sides and still on asterisk with PJSIP 
asterisk with SIP are unavaileble
Question are simple
Why on asterisk with PJSIP  endpoint with SIP-channel are unavailable, and how to fix it ?

Comment: This question is like "why the car is not go and how to fix". Becuase you have to understend what are you doing maybe?

Comment: @arheops 
Maybe You can explain to me what am i doing wrong?
Is it possible to configure interconnect between asterisk with chan_sip and asterisk with chan_pjsip ?(i cannot find any information about that)
In my first post i show all configuration on my servers and i admit, i dont see misconfiguration about nat(as You suggest), but when i fixt that, it still not work.
Can You share with some help?

Comment: There is zero issues in interconnect chan_sip with any sip endpoint and any sip endpoint to pjsip. Also no issues with chan_sip to chan_pjsip. However you should understand what is nat for, how network structure affect sip etc etc.  There are no info and not think anyone will test your config instead of you just to find where is error. You can check sip debugging guide or this command list. https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-cli/#SIPchannelcommands

Comment: @arheops
i think You don't understand my problem and question.
my both asterisk are in the same LAN network
and i try to connect two asterisk 
one with chan_SIP (12.8.0)
one with chan_PJSIP ( 18.2.1)
on side chan_SIP i can see my ast with chan_PJSIP - it has OK status
on side chan_PJSIP i see that ast with chan_SIP are Unavailable
i think that configuration NAT is not a problem in this case.

Can You point in my config what is wrong ?(change NAT to NO or YES have no positive results)
There is possibility to connect two asterisk with different chanels? or not?

Comment: have you tried removing the lines permit = Y.Y.Y.Y /permit=X.X.X.X 
deny = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 and make an open communication without restriction to  see if it works then also I think the permit configuration needs to be reciprocated